# Target host is not specified exception while calling BAPI from Java using SAP Cloud SDK version 3.0

Tags: java, sap-cloud-sdk, s4hana

I am working on a POC currently where I need to call a BAPI inside S/4HANA On-Premise from a cloud application using Java. For this I am using SAP Cloud SDK.

For initial setup I followed these steps from the guide "[Set Up Your Local Infrastructure to Develop with SAP Cloud SDK](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-setup.html)".

I am trying to call `BAPI_COSTCENTER_GETLIST1` from my application. Here is the code snippet:

```
final BapiRequestResult resultGetCostCenters = new BapiRequest("BAPI_COSTCENTER_GETLIST1")
 .withExporting("CONTROLLINGAREA", "BAPI0012_GEN-CO_AREA", "0001")
 .withTable("COSTCENTERLIST", "BAPI0012_CCLIST").end()
 .withTableAsReturn("BAPIRET2")
 .execute(destination);
```

And here the declaration of `destination` variable:

```
Map<String, String> destinationProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
destinationProps.put("Name", "SampleDestination");
destinationProps.put("URL", "abcdefg.wdf.sap.corp");
destinationProps.put("Type", "HTTP");
destinationProps.put("Password", "<system_password>");
destinationProps.put("Authentication", "BasicAuthentication");
destinationProps.put("User", "<system_user>");

final Destination destination= new DefaultDestination(destinationProps);
```

But from `execute()`, one exception is being thrown which says:

> org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified

Here is the complete stack trace:

> ```
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.exception.RequestExecutionException: BapiRequest
>       com.sap.csc.CostCenterCreationServlet.retrieveCostCenterList(CostCenterCreationServlet.java:69)
>       failed [total: N/A, build payload: 0.243255s, execute request: N/A, parse
>       response: N/A]
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.rfc.exception.RemoteFunctionException:
>       com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.exception.RequestExecutionException:
>       BapiRequest com.sap.csc.CostCenterCreationServlet.retrieveCostCenterList(CostCenterCreationServlet.java:69)
>       failed [total: N/A, build payload: 0.243255s, execute request: N/A, parse
>       response: N/A]
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.rfc.SoapTransaction.execute(SoapTransaction.java:70)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.rfc.RemoteFunctionRequestExecutor.execute(RemoteFunctionRequestExecutor.java:46)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.rfc.BapiRequest.execute(BapiRequest.java:78)
>     at com.sap.csc.CostCenterCreationServlet.retrieveCostCenterList(CostCenterCreationServlet.java:73)
>     at com.sap.csc.CostCenterCreationServlet.doGet(CostCenterCreationServlet.java:39)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.lambda$doFilter$1(RequestAccessorFilter.java:71)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:317)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.ThreadContextCallable.call(ThreadContextCallable.java:247)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.thread.AbstractThreadContextExecutor.execute(AbstractThreadContextExecutor.java:319)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestAccessorFilter.doFilter(RequestAccessorFilter.java:71)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpCachingHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpCachingHeaderFilter.java:80)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.java:41)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(RestCsrfPreventionFilter.java:113)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
> Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.exception.RequestExecutionException: BapiRequest com.sap.csc.CostCenterCreationServlet.retrieveCostCenterList(CostCenterCreationServlet.java:69) failed [total: N/A, build payload: 0.243255s, execute request: N/A, parse response: N/A]
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpHttpRequestExecutor.execute(ErpHttpRequestExecutor.java:662)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpHttpRequestExecutor.execute(ErpHttpRequestExecutor.java:410)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.rfc.SoapTransaction.execute(SoapTransaction.java:65)
>     ... 44 more
> Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.HttpClientWrapper.execute(HttpClientWrapper.java:94)
>     at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpHttpRequestExecutor.execute(ErpHttpRequestExecutor.java:646)
>     ... 46 more
> Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Target host is not specified
>     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultRoutePlanner.java:71)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:125)
>     at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
> ```

I have tried providing http or https at the starting of the URL. But still nothing seems to work. Though I am new in this but I assume calling BAPI is different than calling any HTTP API. In that case how to approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `destinationProps.put("URL", "http://abcdefg.wdf.sap.corp");` ?

Comment: yes. It returns connection timeout.

Comment: Are you able to access this web service using Soap Ui or some tool other than java? Is any firewall or something preventing access to this service in your machine?

Comment: I tried pinging from my command prompt and it returns a response.

Comment: Is the error occurring in a deployed cloud application or do you see the error locally?

Comment: I think `abcdefg.wdf.sap.corp` is only available in your intranet. You need to configure a _Cloud Connector_ which acts as a proxy between _SCP_ and _S4HANA_.

Comment: @AlexanderDümont, I see the error locally. I have not deployed it. So do we need to call it with `http` or `https` at the beginning ?

Comment: @AlexanderDümont - Please note that I am still running this code locally from SAP intranet (connected to corporate network) and hence, there is no need to cloud connector right now... Ofcourse we will use it via cloud connector when we deploy it on SCP.
Right now, we want to run this program locally within intranet

Comment: @arunava04: Is your target system running SAP S/4HANA On-Premise or SAP S/4HANA Cloud edition?

Comment: @Emdee, It is On-Premise.

Comment: What you wanna do is technically not supported: You want to invoke a BAPI *from your localhost* via the transport protocol RFC using the JCo library (used behind the scenes via the SAP Cloud SDK). The usage of JCo requires to run your app on SAP Cloud Platform. Then, you can leverage the `DestinationAccessor` like so: `DestinationAccessor.tryGetDestination("my-destination-name")` instead of creating your `Destination` manually.

Comment: @Emdee, Thank you very much for your cooperation. I will try to get it done after deploying.